# What is the difference in terms of pronunciation of /eɪl/ and /el/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

For example:
   hail vs. hell, 
   tail vs. tell, 
   fail vs. fell.

Comment: Have you tried checking the pronunciations online? You may listen to online dictionaries that provide sound files.

Comment: You can hear the differences by listening to the recorded sounds on most online dictionaries, for example http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hail. Note that these are typical AmE speakers: in the Southern states, they tend to make words longer, and so hell would end up sounding like hail. I once worked with a Texan who could turn the letter F into  a three-syllable word.

Comment: @JavaL - Another good resource –particularly for regional differences – is [forvo.com](http://forvo.com/word/fell/#en), where you can hear citizens from the UK, US, Canada, and Australia pronounce [various](http://forvo.com/word/various/#en) [words](http://forvo.com/word/words/#en). It's not authoritative, but it's valuable in that it shows a wide [range](http://forvo.com/word/scallops/#en) of acceptable pronunciations.

Comment: @J.R. very interesting. The last speaker for [hell] (http://forvo.com/word/hell/#en) is definitely a southern belle (doubtless pronounced "bail" by her).

Comment: /ei/ begins with /e/ and ends with /i/, the sound is composed of two vowels. /e/ consists only of a single vowel.

Comment: @JavaLatte Note, however, that her off-glide in the diphthongal is something between [ə] and [ʊ], not [i] or [ɪ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/eɪ/ is a [diphthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong), and /e/ is simply a vowel.

For help actually pronouncing these words, here are some tips:

- /eɪ/ sounds like the pronunciation of the letter A (long A), plus an uh sound. Do you know how to pronounce `hey`? It makes an h + letter A sound. Same thing with `hail`. `hail` sounds like hey-ul.
- /e/ is simply a short E sound. `Hell` is pronounced hel. Coincidentally, the el sound here is the same pronunciation as the letter L. So combine an H sound with saying the letter L. `Hell`.

Comment: So the same goes for bell, tell and fell too?

Comment: @LittleStrawpurple Yes. Those are /e/ words. They all rhyme with hell.